# Валидация rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

Существует валидация для полей контактных данных. jquery проверка проверяет поля, но необходимо на уровне модели создать валидацию. Проблема в том, что при данном варианте, одно из поля не может быть удалено, так как не проходит валидация. Как мне правильно записать валидацию, чтоб если телефона, нет, то проверялось поле email по валидации, ну или наоборот.

Модель.

```
validates :contact_email, format:{ :with => /@/}
  validates :contact_tel, format:{ :with => /^[0-9-()+]{6,16}$/}
  validate :email_xor_tel




private

    def email_xor_tel
      unless contact_email.blank? ^ contact_tel.blank? || contact_email.present? & contact_tel.present?
        errors.add(:base, "")
      end
    end
```

Контроллер

```
def update_info
        @profiles=InfoDesk.find(params[:id])        
        if params[:commit].present?
            if params.require(:info_desk).permit(:contact_email).present?
                n='Обновлен email'
            elsif params.require(:info_desk).permit(:contact_tel).present?
                n='Обновлен tel'
        end
            r=@profiles.update_attributes(params_prof)
            r.present? ? n=n : n='не обновлено'
        redirect_to :back, notice: n
        end
    end
```

Была идейка попробовать записать прям в методе через match, но она не сработала, видимо не правильно прописывал.

Comment: Pro tip: для булеанов вместо `^` обычно используют `!=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

написал вчера валидацию сам, мб, кому то будет полезно.

```
validates :contact_email, if: -> { contact_email.present?}, format:{ :with => /@/}
      validates :contact_tel, if: -> { contact_tel.present? }, format:{ :with => /[0-9\-()+]{6,16}/}
      validates :contact_email, presence: {if: -> { contact_tel.blank?}}
      validates :contact_tel, presence: {if: -> { contact_email.blank?}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам просто нужно **три валидации**:

- Что телефон верный или пустой (добавить `allow_blank: true`)

  - Об `allow_blank` есть в [документации к `validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates).
- Что email верный или пустой (тоже добавить `allow_blank: true`)
- Что телефон **или** email не пуст (`.present?`)

  Если нужно именно **исключающее** или, оно же XOR, то

  ```
  unless contact_email.present? != contact_tel.present?
    # ...
  ```

  А если дизъюнкция, OR, то:

  ```
  unless contact_email.present? || contact_tel.present?
    # ...
  ```